# Is Quarkus rest client parallel connections limited to 256

Tags: netty, quarkus, vert.x, quarkus-rest-client

I have a client to request remote server

```java
Multi.createFrom()
      .items(
          userInfoList.stream())
      .onItem()
      .transformToUniAndMerge(
           userInfo -> {
              System.out.println( personInfo.toString() );
              restClientService.aRESTClientService( userInfo );
           }
      )
```

rest client :

```java
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/xxx")
@RegisterRestClient
public interface RestClientService {
    @GET
    @Path("/xxxx")
    Uni<ResultDto<String>> aRESTClientService(UserInfo userInfo);
}
```

am I doing something wrong ?
or is there something that can be configured

Comment: Have you tried setting `io.quarkus.rest.client.connection-pool-size`?

Comment: @geoand  I setted `quarkus.rest-client.connection-pool-size=1024`  `quarkus.vertx.event-loops-pool-size=1024`  `quarkus.http.io-threads=1024` and `quarkus.http.limits.max-connections=1024` but parallel connections is also limited to 256. my Quarkus version is `2.7.0.Final`

Comment: can you put a reproducer to github or gitlab ?

Comment: @ozkanpakdil [link](https://github.com/xiyuanpingtadi/quarkus-restclient-test)  this is my demo project,Thank you for your advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this will help, but I had a similar issue. I had similar code:

```java
@Scheduled(every = "1s")
void processRequests() {
    
    // assume pendingRequests is an unlimited incoming stream
    Multi.createBy().repeating().supplier(pendingRequests::poll)
    ... // rest client calling each request
}
```

The throughput of this application was exactly 256, and I thought it was due to some limitation in the client; but no, it was because the stream was overflowing after 256 polls. You might be able to increase the throughput by having multiple `Multi` streams consuming from `userInfoList.stream()`. Also, use a counter to see how many items you were able to consume before overflowing; you might find out that overflowing is the issue.

#### UPDATE

A came across an article that explained the magical *256* number (https://pandepra.medium.com/project-reactors-flatmap-and-backpressure-fba97472d625). I Also did some testing to understand how `flatMap` works. So `flatMap`'s request number is 256, so you are stuck with processing at most 256 items. Also, after ***n*** items have been processed (sent to downstream subscribers), ***n*** items will be requested again, always up to 256 (`flatMap` holds an internal queue with max of 256 items). In my first description I was overflowing since `poll()` was pushing more than 256 items. If you want to increase this number you can do:

```java
// increase the concurrency value in `merge` (default is 256)
Multi...
.onItem().transformToUni(n -> Uni.createFrom()...).merge(500)

// OR have multiple streams consuming 
Multi.createBy().merging().streams(List.of(
        // each stream here has a flatMap
        multi1(),
        multi2()
    ))
```

Not sure if there is any major difference with my suggestions above though. Finally, `log()` is you friend. I have been playing around with `log()` to understand what each operator is doing in between.

Comment: You're right.
and I find this code : 
```java 
return merge(Queues.BUFFER_S);
```
[link](https://github.com/smallrye/smallrye-mutiny/blob/main/implementation/src/main/java/io/smallrye/mutiny/groups/MultiFlatten.java#L80)

and this:
```java 
public static final int BUFFER_S = Math.max(16,Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("mutiny.buffer-size.s", "256")));
```

from `smallrye-mutiny`

So we can set JVM startup parameters like `-Dmutiny.buffer-size.s=1024` to configure it